# Bootstrap Navbar won't get colored when using with Django

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm using Django to create an E-Commerce Website. Used Bootstrap navbar in it, but the css I copied from [here](https://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/e74c3cc0392becf0f1ffbbbc0) doesn't work when I use it within the {%block css %} tag.

I'm uploading the html here. Any help is largely appreciated.

Also, if anybody needs the entire project to get an idea of what might be causing an issue, [here's the project.](https://github.com/CodeSadhu/Veronicart-The_Ecom_WebApp)

**basic.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <style>
{% block css %}

.navbar {
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
}

.navbar .navbar-text {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar .navbar-text a {
    color: #ffbbbc;
}

.navbar .navbar-text a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-text a:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #c0392b;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #c0392b;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle .navbar-toggler-icon {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse,
.navbar .navbar-form {
    border-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar .navbar-link {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #ffbbbc;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
        color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
    .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
        color: #ffbbbc;
    }
    .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
        color: #ffbbbc;
        background-color: #c0392b;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
        color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
        color: #ffbbbc;
    }
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
        color: #ffbbbc;
        background-color: #c0392b;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
        color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
        color: #ffbbbc;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
        color: #ffbbbc;
        background-color: #c0392b;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
        color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
    .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
        color: #ffbbbc;
    }
    .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
        color: #ffbbbc;
        background-color: #c0392b;
    }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
}

{% endblock %}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/shop">Veronicart</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/shop">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/shop/about">About Veronicart</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/shop/tracker">Product Tracking</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/shop/contact">Help and Support</a>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-2" id="popcart" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">


  Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>)
</button>
  </div>
</nav>

  {% block body %} {% endblock %}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  {% block js %} {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'mainShop/basic.html' %}

{% block css %}

.col-md-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: blue;
}

.col-md-3 img {
    width: 170px;
    height: 200px;
}

body .carousel-indicator li {
    background-color: blue;
}

body .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0;
}

body .carousel-control-prev-icon,
body .carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-color: blue;
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    padding-top: 222px;
}

body .no-padding {
    padding-left: 0, padding-right: 0;
}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% load static %}
<div class="container">

    <!--Slideshow starts here -->
    {% for product, range, nSlides in allProds %}
    <h5 class="my-4">Flash Sale On {{product.0.category}} - Recommended Items</h5>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="demo{{forloop.counter}}" class="col carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

                {% for i in range %}
                <li data-target="#demo{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="{{i}}"></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

            <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">

                <div class="carousel-item active">

                    {% for i in product %}
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card-deck">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">{{i.desc}}</p>
                                    <button id="pr{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- left and right controls for the slide -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %} {% block js %}
<script>
    console.log('working');
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart') == null) {
        var cart = {};
    } else {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = Object.keys(cart).length;
    }
    $('.cart').click(function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        var idstr = this.id.toString();
        console.log(idstr);
        if (cart[idstr] != undefined) {
            cart[idstr] = cart[idstr] + 1;
        } else {
            cart[idstr] = 1;
        }
        console.log(cart);
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
        document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = Object.keys(cart).length;
    });
    $('#popcart').popover();
    document.getElementById("popcart").setAttribute('data-content', '<h5>See what you wanna order!</h5>');
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good practice to load the css as a block into the .html file, instead, what you should do is:

- Create a 'css' folder inside your static folder.
- Move your styles.css(currently inside your templates folder) to the created folder 'css'.
- Change this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` into this:

  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">`
- Add this to the top of your basic.html file: `{% load staticfiles %}`, just after this: `<!doctype html>`\

Now you can remove that css block from your **basic.html**. Hope that helps!

Comment: This works, but now my card layout is getting messed up. Badly messed up. Try it yourself in my project (I've provided my github link in the question) and if there's a workaround, please post it! Anyways, thanks for this!

Comment: @AtharvaPatwardhan did you commit the last changes? You didn't do anything of what I've wrote.